# VBA Create menu at runtime

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA macros, which create menu and toolbar at runtime(in the event Workbook_New or Workbook_Open). It works fine at Excel 2010, but at 2013, when I programmcatically create new workbook, menu creation is not invoked, but menu contains exactly the same elements like in toolbar(also they are different). What's happens in 2013 Excel and why, if I have already configured menu, in next workbook it replaces with another menu(which I didn't create)?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a compatibility issue. Some items are not supported in higher versions of excel. One example is the Calendar Date picker. In higher versions of excel they no longer support that object, they have replaced it with another object.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d147b5fa-ab97-43a9-8459-787df1e5fb38/date-picker-is-missing-again-in-excel-2010-full-installation-windows-xp?forum=isvvba

Comment: Thank you! I replace MenuBars with CommandBars(and I need to replace some functions, connected with using exactly CommandBars). Now working at 2010 and 2013